# Difference between Flight size and congestion window

Tags: networking, tcp

I am inspecting a TCPlive trace and have come across the flight size variable. Could anyone explain how it differs from the congestion window variable??

Answer (score 2):

FLIGHT SIZE : amount of data that has been sent but not yet acknowledged (acked).

CONGESTION WINDOW (cwnd) : state variable that limits the amount of data a TCP sender can send. At any given time, a TCP sender must not send data with a sequence number higher than the sum of the highest acknowledged sequence number and the minimum of cwnd and rwnd.

RECEIVER WINDOW (rwnd) : the most recently advertised receiver window.

Info from [RFC 2581](http://www.opalsoft.net/qos/TCP-1010.htm)